# Can you run multiple instances of webpack at once?

Tags: parallel-processing, gulp, webpack

Let's say I have an array of components, that need to spit out their own source, as they wont always be included together, it needs to be it's own bundle. The idea is that there will eventually be 100's of components, and they can be cherry picked whenever.

However, when using [webpack-stream](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream) with gulp, even though I'm dynamically registering the tasks, and that I can see they're running sequentially, it only runs one webpack stream by the looks of it, but seems to output it's bundle from the SECOND component, into the first components directory.

[image]

It's a pretty simple build process, it's an array of components like so:

```
var components = [
    {'name : 'a', src : './foo/bar/entrya.js', dest : '/dir/a'},
    {'name : 'b', src : './foo/bar/entryb.js', dest : '/dir/b'},
];
```

Relatively simple right? Then to register the tasks, it's something like this:

```
components.forEach(component => {
    gulp.task(component.name, cb => {

        function task(component) {
            return gulp.src(component.src)
            .pipe($.webpackStream(webpackConfig))
            .pipe(component.dest(component.dest));
        }

        return task.apply(this, [component, cb]);
    });
});
```

This is an incredibly dumbed down version of what I have, but it's pretty much the same thing, dynamically generates and then later on we run those tasks sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webpack-stream` can handle multiple entry points and multiple builds per multiple entry points.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('build', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/entry.js']) // entry.js file doesn't need to exist 
    .pipe(webpack({
      entry:  {
        a : __dirname + "/foo/bar/entrya.js",
        b : __dirname + "/foo/bar/entryb.js"
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dir/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your build is not running in parallel. you are just sequentially registering tasks. However you can run those tasks in parallel as child processes. One good option you can use is [parallel-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-webpack).